# Tsql denormalize a table with text values

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I have a table like

```
UserID      Attribute      Value
1           Name           Peter
1           Sex            male
1           Nationality    UK
2           Name           Sue
```

And need a result like

```
UserId     Name    Sex   Nationality .....
1          Peter   male  Uk
2          Sue .....
```

Looks like crosstab - in MS Access that works if I take First(Value) - in T SQL I cannot get it to work with Value being a text field

Any ideas?

Comment: `select * from table ( pivot min(UserID) for Atrrribute in ([Name],[Sex],[Nationality])) as piv; group by UserID `

Comment: Yes - but Name, Sex, Nationality is datadriven - I don't know which attributes I have

Comment: @vijaykumar-hadalgiv, nice work sir.  beat me to it with record time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (UserID INT, Attribute VARCHAR(20),Value VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1,'Name','Peter'),
(1,'Sex','male'),
(1,'Nationality','UK'),
(2,'Name','Sue')


SELECT * FROM @TABLE
PIVOT ( MAX(Value)
        FOR Attribute
        IN ([Name], [Sex], [Nationality]))P
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════╦═══════╦══════╦═════════════╗
║ UserID ║ Name  ║ Sex  ║ Nationality ║
╠════════╬═══════╬══════╬═════════════╣
║      1 ║ Peter ║ male ║ UK          ║
║      2 ║ Sue   ║ NULL ║ NULL        ║
╚════════╩═══════╩══════╩═════════════╝
```